# Psexec - can't execute on french windows

Tags: c#, windows, translation, account, psexec

I got a problem with [psexec.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec) from windows.

I'm on a french windows and my local account are translate like "AUTORITE NT/Système" instead of "NT AUTHORITY/System". So I can't run psexec.exe because I think the software does not take the french translation of the local users.

I develop in C # a program that allows to choose a user with [DirectoryObjectPickerDialog()](https://github.com/Tulpep/Active-Directory-Object-Picker) and execute the program with the selected user.

So my question is whether anyone knows if we can run psexec.exe with the account in French or you have to translate it? Or maybe launch it with the Sid of the user ?

Also, if anyone knows how to translate French names into English names automatically it would help me a lot.

Thank in advance.

Comment: `psexec` specifically uses `-s` to run as the system account, not a particular user. Are you saying that doesn't work? Specifying the user name as `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM` (whether localized or not) shouldn't work in any case since you can't supply a password for it. In general, any account name that's localized can't be passed as-is to `psexec`, since all those accounts are "special" and have no (known) passwords.

Comment: I can run `psexec` with the user `NT AUTHORITY\System` without use -s and without give any password for it. So I think it detects that this is the local system account. But if i want to use an other local account than local system, i can't because no other `-?` exists for other accounts . Should I make a switch to translate each name?

Comment: Does something like `NT AUTHORITY\Network Service` work? It's weird that `psexec` would be able to translate English names, but not process localized ones. I don't see how it does that unless it has special case logic for all of these. Having said that, there aren't a lot of interesting `NT AUTHORITY` accounts to support (`System`, `LocalService`, `NetworkService`, that's about all that's interesting), and the other accounts aren't localized.